# design a graph with latex

Tags: draw

I heard that via Latex we can draw electrical circuit if we respect certain coding:
What is the latex code of the corresponding circuit:

[image]

And thank you in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Have you considered checking the [circuitikz package](https://ctan.org/pkg/circuitikz)?

Comment: Welcome! The package is probably `circuitikz`. You will find more about it by looking at its documentation and/or by searching for `circuitikz` in this forum.

Comment: There's also  `pst-circ` in the `pstricks` family.

Answer (score 2):

For my humble opinion to realize a quick circuit you can use Circuit Macros.Cirkuit contain great set of macros that can be used to produce high-quality diagrams for inclusion in a document .tex. The link for this program is:

[Circuit](http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/cirkuit.html).